# Mac : I want the file open dialog in an app like Xcode to open in the last-visited folder 

Tags: macos

... so that I do not have to browse over and over again when adding several existing files from the same or a nearby folder.

Is it possible to configure this, and how/where in settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [third-party product](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/) that does that and more.